# Linebreaks in middle of URL in HTML

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have this strange issue, where I get random linebreaks in my HTML when I copy & paste links from mails I get.

The problem is, linebreaks look exactly like any other whitespace and on long lines I have problems seeing if there is any linebreaks.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but we are also using emailing system that doesn't like breaklines in middle of an element.

Is there a way to see these without manually scanning all the lines, which is impossible due to amount of mails we are sending.

Regex maybe?
I'm using Notepad++ as an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, you can use "Extended" mode in the FIND Option. Use "\r\n" to scan all the new lines in the file. Use "\r" to find all carriage returns in the file.